# Issues while installing Docker on Windows 10 home edition

Tags: docker

I am getting below error When I try to install Docker on Windows 10 Home Edition.

```
[21:20:49.129] [InstallWorkflow] Pre-requisite failed: Docker for Windows requires Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise version 14393, or Windows server 2016 RTM to run
```

Can I Install Docker on Windows 10 Home Edition?

Comment: You will need to use [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) instead of standard Docker. Docker now uses native Windows virtualization, which is not supported on Win 10 Home.

Answer (score 47):

Edit Windows Version in Registry

1. Press Windows + R and write regedit
2. In the Registry Editor, go to \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
3. Right-click on EditionID and Click Modify
4. Change Value Data to "Professional"
5. Press OK.
6. Install Docker

After the installation, you can change the EditionID back to "Core"

Comment: Seems strange to do this but seems to work. Thanks man!

Answer (score 25):

As the error says, you cannot use Docker in the Home edition. You need "Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise version 14393, or Windows server 2016 RTM."

Check out their [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install), which mentions, on 04/05/2018:

> The current version of Docker for Windows runs on 64bit Windows 10
>   Pro, Enterprise and Education (1607 Anniversary Update, Build 14393 or
>   later).

As already mentioned in the comments, you might want to try the legacy [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/):

> Docker Toolbox is for older Mac and Windows systems that do not meet
>   the requirements of Docker for Mac and Docker for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this!  It saved me. I spent hours trying to make Docker-compose / Docker Daemon work on Ubuntu via Windows10 in vain until I read this article confirming that it is in fact impossible (https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4) unless you have Docker Desktop for Windows which doesnt work on the Home Edition ... finally my problem was solved installing Docker Toolbox.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Docker for Windows requires Hyper-V which is not included in Home edition.
You'll need to upgrade Windows to the Education or Pro edition.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install

Also see this comment on [GitHub](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1973).

Comment: Hyper-V has been added to newer editions Windows 10 Home and yet it still will not install.

Comment: @Taiger maybe the installer checks for the version and not for the feature it really needs (Hyper-V in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can already install Docker Desktop on Windows 10 Home.
This is how I did it:

1. You need to join Windows Insiders Program because you need WSL 2
   [image: Windows Insiders Program]
2. You need to download the specific version of Docker Desktop: https://download-stage.docker.com/win/edge/41944/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe which has a required change - allows install it on Windows 10 Home.
   [image: Docker Desktop Version]

Comment: Actually Windows Insiders Program no longer required. Windows 10 Version 2004 has been officially released.

Comment: That's true, and you no longer need the edge version of docker - Windows 10 Home support is already in stable version of Docker for Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Those who have Windows Home Edition can now download and install Docker Desktop from below link.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install-windows-home/

Answer (score 0):

Although not on Win10 Home per se, for evaluation purposes you can install Docker Desktop on a Win10 Pro virtual machine (VMWare player is my personal choice). You'll need to install VMWare Workstation Player which is free, and obtain a perfectly legal Win10 Pro image from microsoft directly here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Be sure to activate the virtualization engine of the machine as Docker relies on Hyper-V:
[image: VMWare virtualization settings]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the problem. (OS- windows 10 home)

1. Join windows insider program. It enables you to update latest content of windows 10. You can find it in the start-> settings. Make sure to select **Release Preview** in the Insider program.(otherwise you will not get latest updates. After the installation you can pause frequent updates)
   [image]
2. Check for windows update and update windows to latest version.(This will take awhile)
   [image]
3. Install WSL 2 Linux kernel
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel

I had below issue because I have tried to install this before updating windows. Please read the document carefully and follow steps.

> If the installer cant find WSL 1 **right click the Linux kernel update
>   installer**, then press uninstall then rerun the installer

4. Now you are ready to update to WSL 2. Follow steps of this doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

- Open PowerShell as Administrator and run:
  **dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart**
- Enable the 'Virtual Machine Platform'
  Open PowerShell as Administrator and run:
  **dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart**
  Restart your machine to complete the WSL install and update to WSL 2.

You can verify whether this by looking at task manager.
[image]

*Set WSL 2 as your default version
In PowerShell:  **wsl --set-default-version 2**

5. Now you can install docker desktop version.
6. Finally https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

This might not work for some. If you find any issues please post. I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone who cannot upgrade their system to pro or professional. Consider installing [Docker Toolbox on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/). For mac users: [Docker Toolbox on Mac](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_mac/)

> Legacy desktop solution. Docker Toolbox is for older Mac and Windows systems that do not meet the requirements of 'Docker Desktop for Mac' and 'Docker Toolbox on Windows'. We recommend updating to the newer applications, if possible.

As per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/), the toolbox includes these Docker tools:

- Docker Machine for running `docker-machine` commands
- Docker Engine for running the `docker` commands
- Docker Compose for running the `docker-compose` commands
- Kitematic, the Docker GUI
- a shell preconfigured for a Docker command-line environment
- Oracle VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest update from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

First of all I'd like to thank the previous respondents to this questions - saved me a lot of time and yes, they are both correct.

Secondly as a small completion to their answer, in case you are wondering where you can get a Pro version of Windows without breaking the bank, you can get a relatively cheap and legal Windows 10 pro cd-key from ebay and upgrade you version from Windows settings -> Activation.

https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=windows+10+pro&_sacat=0&_sop=15

Just make sure you read the sold product description well and eventually the reviews if there are so that you know what to expect (if you encounter any issue, ebay will refund your purchase).
Best of luck to you all!